# Get a slack notification if mentioned on Github

Tags: github, integration, github-api, slack, slack-api

Zapier has a very cool feature you can add which will send a slack notification every time you are mentioned on github.

https://zapier.com/apps/github/integrations/slack/1596/send-a-github-new-mention-to-slack-as-a-new-message

Unfortunately it is not a free service. Does anyone have a way to add this kind of integration directly with slack or something else? It would be really useful for my work environment.

Answer (score 39):

UPDATE:
This is how you do it in a Github Native way:

1. Install the [Github Slack app](https://slack.github.com/)
2. Go to your [settings/reminders](https://github.com/settings/reminders)
3. Select the org you care about
4. click `Enable real-time alerts`
5. select `You are mentioned in a comment`

[image]

---

While it doesn't seem like github's slack app will do what you're asking for yet ([track this issue for future updates](https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/380)), But I've found 2 alternatives:

1. [this](https://pipedream.com/@pravin/notify-me-in-slack-if-i-m-mentioned-in-a-github-issue-p_YyClNq/readme) example using pipedream integrations.
   The good news is that pipedream is free, but the bad news is that pipedream is free.
2. Using [PullReminders](https://pullreminders.com/)'s [pullpanda](https://pullpanda.com/) as explained in [this comment](https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/380#issuecomment-452355593) (unclear if still functional after GitHub acquired the company behind PullReminders, though). If this works, it should be free.

You won't have to pay, but I have no idea about the security aspects of integrating with a free 3rd party that has no commitment or clear incentive to keep your system secure.

Comment: It does seem like this is buggy or incomplete - 
I added a comment in the files view of a random commit (example below), and I was not notified
Can anyone inform people in GH?

https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/465ce90c92979bc0015c1d3354109cbffbc8bc3b#r41644628

Comment: If anyone is interested, PullReminders was shut down 4 years ago. I developed with a friend an alternative: https://axolo.co it helps tech teams review PR in Slack by creating ephemeral channels and inviting the right people instead of notifying the whole team/repo